# Form data is passing in html table

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am submitting the form data by using fetch API and then I want to show some variable values in HTML table. But it's not working as it's supposed to be. I am getting the value in the HTML table as **"undefined"**. I can't get what my mistake is. I have tried to remove all unnecessary parts to debug. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

**Console screen output**

[Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l15Ci.png)

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from home import views

urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.home, name='home')

]
```

**views.py**

```
from json import dumps

def home(request):

    context={}

    if request.method=="POST":

        options_value=request.POST.get('options_value')

        value=request.POST.get('value')

        print(type(options_value),value)

        context['options_value'] = options_value

        context['value']= value

        return JsonResponse(context, safe=False)

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

**index.html**

```
<form method="POST" action="" id="form">
      {% csrf_token %}
          <select
            class="form-select"
            aria-label="Default select example"
            name="options_value"
            id="options_value"
          >
            <option disabled hidden selected>---Select---</option>
            <option value="1">Profile UID</option>
            <option value="2">Employee ID</option>
            <option value="3">Email ID</option>
            <option value="4">LAN ID</option>
          </select>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter Value"
            name="value"
            id="value"
          />

          <input
            class="btn btn-primary"
            type="submit"
            value="Submit"
            style="background-color: #3a0ca3"
          />
    </form>

<table style="display: table" id="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">ProfileUID :</th>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
           
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">First Nane :</th>
              <td></td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
<script>
      let form = document.getElementById("form");
      let options_value = document.getElementById("options_value");
      let val = document.getElementById("value");
      const csrf = document.getElementsByName("csrfmiddlewaretoken")[0].value;


      form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const newform = new FormData();
        newform.append("options_value", options_value.value);
        newform.append("value", value.value);
        newform.append("csrfmiddlewaretoken", csrf);
        fetch("", {
          method: "POST",
          body: newform,
        })

      .then((response) => {

            console.log(response.json());
            let data = response.json();
            console.log("Success:", data);
            let tds = document.querySelectorAll("table tr td");
            tds[0].innerHTML = data.options_value;
            tds[1].innerHTML = data.value;

          })
       .catch(error => {
       console.error('Error:', error);
       });

      });
    </script>
```

Comment: As I have put "response.text()" , I am able to see my whole source code in console after clicking the submit button.

Comment: Now it is showing "Success : undefined" but the values are not visible on the table row. That I what I want to be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you use **Django-Template** to display data or you use **JavaScript** if you want to submit your form using **JavaScript** then you've to use **JavaScript** to display data I'm sharing **JavaScript** approch let me know if you want to use **Django-Template** then I'll add that.

---

Just use [**`JsonResponse`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)

```
def home(request):
    context={}

    if request.method == "POST":

        options_value = request.POST.get('options_value')

        value = request.POST.get('value')

        print(type(options_value),value)

        context['options_value'] = options_value
        context['value'] = value

        print(context)

        return JsonResponse(context)

    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

and inside your **JavaScript** do like this

```
fetch("",
  {
    method: "POST",
    body: newform,
  })
  .then(response => response.json());
  .then(data => {
    console.log('Success:', data);
    let tds = document.querySelectorAll('table tr td')
    tds[0].innerHTML = data.options_value
    tds[1].innerHTML = data.value
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
```

and this is how your **HTML** will look

```
<table style="display: table" id="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <th scope="row">ProfileUID :</th>
       <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <th scope="row">First Nane :</th>
       <td></td>
    </tr>
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.write()` to rewrite the html of the page with the data you receive from the fetch request.

```js
fetch(url,option) // Abstracted for brevity
.then(response => response.text())
.then(data => {document.write(data);})
```

Although this would satisfy your needs, however, it's not the best way to update the values in the document. By rewriting the entire HTML for the document, all stylesheets, images and scripts have to be loaded and executed again, which is unnecessary. Additionally, injecting scripts like this is dangerous.

In case you are performing operations such as saving the results of the form to a database, it's better to return a `JSONResponse` indicating the result of the operation to the `fetch` request, and then update the HTML using JavaScript.

Ex.
**views.py**

```py
from django.http import JSONResponse

def home(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
    # Operations
    if success:
      return JSONResponse(
        {
          "successful": True,
          "message": success_message,
          "data": {}, # Anything else you'd like to send, like Profile UID and Name
        }
      )
    else:
      return JSONResponse(
        {
          "successful": False,
          "message": error_message,
          "data": {}, # Anything else you'd like to send
        }
      )
  # Handle other request methods
```

**index.html**'s `fetch` request

```js
fetch(url, options)
.then(response => response.json()) // returns a promise that converts response to a JS Object
.then(data => { // data is a JS object, which is 
                // the same as the dictionary we had in views.py
  if (data.successful === true) {
    // You can set IDs for the `td` where you would like to update the values
    // like "profile-uid" and "profile-name"
    // data.data is the dictionary returned by the JSONResponse 
    // that has additional information, which is also converted to a JS Object
    document.getElementById('profile-uid').textContent = data.data.puid; 
    document.getElementById('profile-name').textContent = data.data.pname;
  }
  else {
    // Handle Errors
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

1st choice) If you're sending a fetch request, I think it's better to use `jsonify({'data':dataJSON})` and get data on the same webpage itself.

2nd choice) On your front-end HTML, you can work on your response by storing it like this. `JSON.parse('{{ context | tojson }}')` in a variable. Make sure you are passing context as a JSON Object from your views.py